# Hello, when I export contributions , tax amount is always 0

Tags: civireport, export, taxes

people register for memberships, amount includes tax. when I export to csv file, tax always show 0

Comment: Hello Alia, welcome to StackExchange! Could you say a bit more about your issue. This will help people to help you. For example you could include information about how  membership and tax is configured on your system and perhaps a screenshot of a contribution showing the tax amount (please ensure to remove any personal information).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.